# Ought cross-posted questions be deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleting-posts, cross-posting

Ought *[different vs differential (adjectives, not nouns)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374995)* be deleted here because it was [also posed to ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57880)? Why not just close it?

Viewpoints appear to differ. [Charles Stewart's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65943/226001) in *[Cross-posting on StackExchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65931)* and [Wikis' answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65945/226001) in the duplicate *[Cross-posting on StackExchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65931)* approve of it.

Comment: There are three "thises" in two sentences. *This*, what is "this"? Post the title of the question if it's a question. If there are answers, tels us where you found them. Make this easier for us and for yourself at the same time.

Comment: You realize that anyone with less than 10k won't understand what you are talking about. Deleted questions are visible to users with 10k. I *would* edit, and fix this important question, but nearly every time I do, you reverse some of the changes and make it "leaner" in some belief that concision is the epitome of correctness. At the very least, include the title and an excerpt of your deleted question.

Comment: Or, more completely: _[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65943/226001) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65945/226001) approve it, 
while many of the answers [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068) would discourage the practice._

Answer (score 5):

Yes, cross-posts should be deleted.

They should not have been posted in the first place, and thus their proper state of existence is none at all.

Note that it was a [diamond moderator, acting in that capacity, who deleted your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/374995/revisions). Here is [his comment regarding that action](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374995/different-vs-differential-adjectives-not-nouns#comment1128865_374995)¹ (**bold emphasis** mine):

> Thank you for being persistent, but **avoid reposting or cross-posting to get more attention**. See: “[How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer? – Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer)” If you want to try another site, ask for migration, or else delete the original before re-asking the question on the other site. See: “[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site? – Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)”. – MetaEd♦︎︎ 8 hours ago

You don’t need more affirmation than that as to the disposition of this site towards that action.

**Please do not cross-post**; if you choose to ignore that injunction, than you should not be surprised or cavil at the obvious consequences.

We — specifically you and I, you asking, me answering — [have discussed this before, on this very site](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5303/55623). In the selfsame question you are asking about, [I brought that discussion back to your attention](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374995/different-vs-differential-adjectives-not-nouns#comment879787_374995). We do not need to discuss it again.

That policy outlined here, on Meta.EL&U, is more pertinent and binding on EL&U than any other statements, pro, contra, or otherwise, that you find on MSE or any other meta site you care to reference².

---

¹<sub>For users < 10k who cannot see it; I’m aware that as OP you can see your own deleted question, and have already read it.</sub>

² <sub>And if you insist on doing so, *you should use the normative link the moderator who deleted your question provided to you in the comment he left when doing so*. The very same link I provided to you *four years ago* when we discussed this the first time. The topmost and accepted answer is “no”, where both the question and the answer has more votes, thus more consensus, thus more weight, than the two *contra* posts you cite. The answer is *no*. You’re going to have to accept that.</sub>

Comment: I've upvoted, but it's kind of ironic that you are now asking on meta how to encourage interesting questions. The question which the OP is referring to is titled *‘different vs differential (adjectives, not nouns)’* and the OP also asks "…Why can't 'different' substitute 'differential' in the following example?…" I'm not convinced that deleting this question did the site or future visitors searching for the same answer any favours. Its biggest handicap were the answers posted, none of whom earned an upvote.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Its biggest handicapped is it was asked somewhere else, first.

Comment: Mmm...if there had been a stellar answer, and upvoted, I doubt the question would have been deleted...

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think questions should be deleted ***just*** because they were cross-posted.

If non-mod users can migrate questions between the two sites, then vote to migrate one of them, and make a note to members of the **other** site to close it as a duplicate of the purported cross-post.

For example, suppose "X" on EL&U was cross-posted as "Y" on ELL:

- migrate "X" to ELL
- leaving a comment on "X" to ask ELL members to close "X" as duplicate of "Y".

There's the theoretical possibility that both will be migrated both ways, but I don't think it would happen all that often.

Otherwise (i.e. if non-mod users can't migrate questions between the two sites), the question ought to attract different kinds of answers on both sites (e.g. EL&U and Physics), so it should be treated independently on each site. Each site can deal with its own question independently: keep open, close, dupe, delete, etc.

Comment: +1 There is no such thing as a duplicate, however, as  'duplicate o a question on another site'. (and that's a good thing)

Comment: Thanks @Araucaria. I've elaborated on the close+dupe idea.

Comment: +1 for "the question ought to attract different kinds of answers on both sites". I'm not sure the "migrate, then dupe" approach would work, though—ordinarily, if a migrated question is closed at the target site that counts as a "migration rejection" and the question is bounced back to the original site. Do you know if that's different for duplicate closure? (I know they do work differently in some other areas.)

Comment: @1006a Good point. I’m not sure how a dupe closure interacts with migration rejection, but I recall a conversation on ELL some time ago where they said migration rejection left a mess in some cases.